# Specflow - using data from external file in feature file

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow, import-from-excel

I am using SpecFlow for my test and looking for a way to using inupt data from excel/csv/json in my feature file. I am treed to use SpecFlow+ Excel but it's not compatible with .NETCore and SpecFlow 3.3.57 which I am using.
I also tried to use Itamaram.Excel.SpecFlowPlugin but it also didn't work.
https://github.com/Itamaram/SpecFlow.Plugin.Base
Is it any way to read input data from external file and write it to my feature file?

Comment: The excel package is using OfficeOpenXml which is support in core : https://www.nuget.org/packages/OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage/

Comment: What is your usecase @MichalG? Why do you want to do it? Feature request to update SpecFlow+ Excel to upvote is here: https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/360012819997-Support-for-SpecFlow-Excel-in-current-SpecFlow-versions

Comment: @AndreasWillich I need to write test for big amount of data which is stored in excel files and update really often

Answer (score 1):

We have a new plugin to get external data from json files.

It is a simple SpecFlow plugin that you can install as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.ExternalData/3.4.32-beta).

Example of usage:

```
@property:email=E-mail_addresses.Valid
Scenario Outline: recording user information on successful registration

Given a visitor registering as "Mike Scott" with email <email>
When the registration completes
Then the account system should record <email> related to user "Mike Scott"

Examples: key examples
  | Variant            | email              |
  | simple valid email | simple@example.com |
```

The json file looks like this:

```json
{ 
  "E-mail addresses": {
    "Valid" :{
      "Simple": "email@domain.com",
      "Dot in the address": "firstname.lastname@domain.com"
    }
  }
}
```

More details are in the blog post about it: https://specflow.org/blog/new-plugin-externaldata-helps-you-improve-test-coverage-quickly/

---

Full disclosure: I am the community manager of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: as the community manager you may want to update your doco as it only states that csv files are the only supported types.

Answer (score 0):

External data don't work with SpecFlow 3.6 version (problem with build application: error Missing generator plugin). External data works on 3.9 version but this version have problem with AfterScenario hooks. All steps passed but finaly test failed (collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute)