# specflow external data using json with many property

Tags: specflow

I am trying to migrate from specflow excel to using a json data file and the [external data plugin](https://specflow.org/blog/new-plugin-externaldata-helps-you-improve-test-coverage-quickly/)

Related to [Specflow - using data from external file in feature file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954892) is there a walkthrough to setup a feature file, and json data file with new `@property` approach to data?

I have a Specflow feature like this, which originally came from Specflow Excel.

```
Feature: EndToEndId

Scenario Outline: Single Payment
    Given a client <clientNo> called <cName>
    And a broker <bName> with book ref <bRef>
    When a deal to <buyOrSell> an amount <fromAmt> of <ccy1> for <ccy2> for value <vDate> at client rate <cRate> and bank rate <bRate>
    Then create a deal <dealNo> with client amt <toCAmt> and cover amt <coverAmt> and PnL <PnL> and profit rate <pRate> and <bYes>
    And add beneficiary <benName> and country <ctry> and pay type <payType> and charge <charge> and <abYes>
    When a credit file <c1> with <c1Name> for <c1Amt> <c1Ccy> for value <c1Date> with ref <EndToEndId1>
    Then CreditNotice gets <fIn1Type> for client <fIn1Client>

Examples: 
    | case                 | clientNo | cName        | bName   | bRef       | buyOrSell | fromAmt | ccy1 | ccy2 | vDate | cRate             | bRate             | dealNo | toCAmt           | coverAmt         | PnL     | pRate    | bYes | benName     | ctry | payType | charge | abYes | c1    | c1Name           | c1Amt            | c1Ccy | c1Date | EndToEndId1      | fIn1Type       | fIn1Client       |
    | T1: 99549 ######     | 99549    | Gherkin Test | MERCURY | 01W3RG5638 | SELL      | 100000  | EUR  | GBP  | SP    | 0.89435           | 0.89935           | ###### | 89435            | 89935            | 500     | 1        | yes  | Gherkin Ben | GB   | CHAPS   | NONE   | yes   | 99549 | Gherkin Test     | 100000           | EUR   | SP     | 99549 ######     | FullFundsIn    | Gherkin Test     |
```

To use the with a json file for the data, am I going to need to define each property again like this:

```
@property:clientNo=clientNo
@property:cName=cName
@property:bName=bName
```

and a json data file like this:

```json
{
    "case": "T-9: 99549 ######",
    "clientNo": "99549",
    "cName": "Gherkin Test",
    "bName": "MERCURY",
    "bRef": "01W3RG5638",
    "buyOrSell": "SELL",
    "fromAmt": "100,000",
    "ccy1": "EUR",
    "ccy2": "GBP",
    "vDate": "SP",
    "cRate": " 0.894350 ",
    "bRate": " 0.894350 ",
    "dealNo": "######",
    "toCAmt": "89,435.00",
    "coverAmt": "89,435.00",
    "PnL": "0.00",
    "pRate": " 1.000000 ",
    "bYes": " yes ",
    "benName": "Gherkin Ben",
    "ctry": "GB",
    "payType": "CHAPS",
    "charge": "NONE",
    "abYes": "yes",
    "c1": "99549",
    "c1Name": "Gherkin Test",
    "c1Amt": "100,000",
    "c1Ccy": "EUR",
    "c1Date": "SP",
    "EndToEndId1": "99549 ######",
    "fIn1Type": "FullFundsIn",
    "fIn1Client": "Gherkin Test"
},
{
    "case": "T-8: 1234 1234",
    "clientNo": "99549",
    "cName": "Gherkin Test",
    "bName": "JUPITER",
    "bRef": "01W3RG5639",
    "buyOrSell": "SELL",
    "fromAmt": "200,000",
    "ccy1": "EUR",
    "ccy2": "GBP",
    "vDate": "SP",
    "cRate": " 0.894350 ",
    "bRate": " 0.894350 ",
    "dealNo": "######",
    "toCAmt": "178,870.00",
    "coverAmt": "178,870.00",
    "PnL": "0.00",
    "pRate": " 1.000000 ",
    "bYes": " yes ",
    "benName": "Gherkin Ben",
    "ctry": "GB",
    "payType": "FASTER",
    "charge": "NONE",
    "abYes": "yes",
    "c1": "99549",
    "c1Name": "Gherkin Test",
    "c1Amt": "200,000",
    "c1Ccy": "EUR",
    "c1Date": "SP",
    "EndToEndId1": "1234 1234",
    "fIn1Type": "BankRec",
    "fIn1Client": "Gherkin Test"
}
```

Thanks for some pointers on how to get the json data into the specflow feature file.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, [edit] your question to include them as plain text code blocks.

Comment: ok, done. not as pretty though ;-)

Comment: I cleaned it up a little bit. You can have a look at the markdown to see how I enabled syntax highlighting. There is a help icon in the question editor with more information.

Answer (score 0):

The SpecFlow.ExternalData plugin is currently limited to a single parameter.
Please upvote the feature request at https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/360015106078-Allow-multiple-parameters-to-be-used-with-External-Data-plugin to get this higher in our backlog priority.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate plugin called Specflow.Contrib.JsonData as part of Nuget packages which accepts JSON data as an input for specflow scenarios. It is an extension to the Specflow.ExternalData plugin. It also accepts multiple properties. Check out https://libraries.io/nuget/SpecFlow.Contrib.JsonData.